# Why CSS is not being applied to textboxes in IE?

Tags: css

The following CSS is working in FF but not in IE.

```
select,input[type=text] {
    width:200px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Depends on the version of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS selector compatibility:**

You might want to take a look at the [css selectors compatibility chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t31). You can also do a [css selectors test](http://www.css3.info/selectors-test/) online.

Here is another [compatibility chart](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/).

**Browser support:**

IE 6 doesn't support much. I don't know your audience, but maybe it is not necessary to support IE 6?

If you don't know your target audience that well, you might want to take a look at [statcounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201105-201110): IE 6 has worldwide about 2.5% market share.

Google [dropped support](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2011/06/our-plans-to-support-modern-browsers.html) for IE 6.

**How to fix it:**

- You could fix this with JavaScript (example: an [jQuery](http://www.impressivewebs.com/buggy-css-selectors-cross-browser-jquery/) article, [another one](http://allcreatives.net/2009/12/03/using-jquery-to-fix-ie6-css-annoyances/))
- Drop support for IE 6
- Use classes / ids for selecting

Comment: I have fixed it using a class. Thanks every one.

Answer (score 1):

are you using IE6?? because IE6 doesn't support  attribute selectors (input[type=text]), you should use a class in order to style them.

try this:
F12, (to display the developer tool) and the document mode is?

Possibly you page has a valid DTD but contains so many errors that IE8 and 9 fallback to Compatibility Mode (Emulate IE7). See Advanced tab of Internet Options - "Recover from rendering errors with compatibility view"

Comment: <input type="text" id="EndDateInputBox" value="" disabled="disabled"> <img height="16" width="16" border="0" onclick="return showCalendar('EndDateInputBox','yyyy-mm-dd');" src="/files/404048/93125/Calendar.png"></td>

Comment: you have to close the input try adding the dash at the end. Use some html validator in order to fix all the html errors, as I mentioned in the answer if you have html errors IE will work as IE7 and it doesn't support attribute selectors. :)

Comment: I pasted in this CSS into a new doc with a simple form and it worked in IE 7,8 and 9. I suspect there's either some other rule messing it up, or like JAiro suggests, the page is getting thrown into quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

IE is not able to use pseudo classes like this one. Which version of IE do you use? **edit:** I'm sorry, I mean attribute selectors as JAiro already said.